# Kali linux(Virtual Box) doesn't detect the physical wifi adapter ( Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160)?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, virtualbox, intel

I have the `Kali 4.14.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.14.12-2kali1 (2018-01-08) x86_64GNU/linux` I followed the instructions [Linux* Support for Intel® Wireless Adapters](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) depicted here for my specific card Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160 I copied the content into `home/lib/firmware/`but still Linux Kali doesn't detect the wi-fi adaptor. What can I do to remedy it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that virtual box does not detect the USB drive?
If that's the case you should add a USB controller in the VM settings.